# Regular Network Packets

Tags: networking

I am working on a project in which I do several tests with packets being passed across a network. The question I am asking is how to find out what regular packets might be like. For instance if someone was doing a regular thing such as checking their email, surfing the web, or chatting on Skype. What would the packets contain that were being transferred? How could I replicate these packets and build them myself? How could I find some on my own computer? I would be thankful for any information on the topic and would be glad to elaborate more on certain areas if necessary. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Packets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_packet) could contain anything-- it depends on the [protocols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communications_protocol), or agreed rules, being used to communicate between two systems.  There are also different layers of protocols which are built upon one another.  You should read up on the [OSI model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model), and read about common protocols used within it (e.g. IP, TCP, UDP, etc. to name just a few).  If you wanted to examine packets that are coming into or going out of a computer, you would use a program (or device) called a [packet analyzer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packet_analyzer) or sniffer.  Try googling on these terms and that should get you started at least.  Networking is a very broad and complex topic.

Comment: Right, I will look into protocols. Do you know of any ways to create "mundane" packets? Or packets that would be normal to see. And malicious Packets. I am trying to test different securities.

Comment: Again, this totally depends on the protocol, or agreed rules, used to communicate. A "packet" is really just a small chunk of data sent between two systems. A "normal" packet follows the rules of the protocol; a "malicious" one contains something that the receiving system doesn't expect and exploits a flaw in that system's handling of unexpected input. You need to specify what protocol we're talking about before we can even begin to say what's normal versus not. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_packet) to learn more about packets.

Comment: OK I will do more research and get back to you tomorrow. Thanks!